# ICS invites are added to calendar, but no acceptance sent

Tags: mail.app

I am working with iCloud, iPhone and Macbook Pro on Yosemite.

I receive ICS calendar invites via mail from a user using Outlook. When I click on the ICS file in the mail, it opens and I can add it to my calendar without a problem. It also syncs nicely on all my devices.

However, the sender of the invite does not get a confirmation, in the meeting properties I'm shown as "did not reply". When I open the invite in my calendar, I have no option to accept or send a notification.

In short: ICS invites are added to my calendar but the organizer does not receive a notification.

How can I send an accept notification?

Comment: Not a single person can suggest something for this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the Contacts app, select your own email address in the list of contacts. In the menu on top of the screen, go to "Card" -> "Make this my card". Ensure your email address is entered as part of your card. Reload calendar. Then it should work, you will get a notification popup with accept/decline buttons. (I just had the same problem, on a Mac running Yosemite)
[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498622)

Comment: That did it: even without reloading I now see appointments that I hadn't previously accepted turn gray and when I click on then the 'accept, decline or maybe' options are available. Can't believe the first and only reply 6 months later actually solves the issue (and I was still experiencing this to this day!). Thank you!

Comment: Perfect—this basically worked for me, I already had my contact card set up, but had to add the missing email to my contact card that's all. Thanks @Phasma.